# Why does object beginning with a period not appear in the global environment pane in rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Create object

```
.object <- 2
```

Confirm object exists in global namespace

```
.object 
# [1] 2
```

yet

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because variables starting with a `.` are *hidden*

If you do `ls()` you'll not find that object. From `?ls`

> all.names
>   a logical value. If TRUE, all object names are returned. If FALSE, names which begin with a . are omitted.

To get that name in the environment you need to do

```
ls(all.names = TRUE)
```

As the object is omitted it is not showing it in the workspace?